# Check if username exists in my own Joomla component form

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-component, joomla-jform

I created a new rule for my own form. This rule should check, if username exists and if user is in one of specified groups.

Can you help me?

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

class JFormRuleUser extends JFormRule
{
    public function test(SimpleXMLElement $element, $value, $group = null, JRegistry $input = null, JForm $form = null)
    {
        // TODO: check if username exists and if user is in one of these groups: X, Y and/or Z

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the JUserHelper class like

```
$id = JUserHelper::getUserId();
if ($id)
{
    if (in_array(JUserHelper::getUserGroups($id), $groupsToCheck))
    {
         return true;
    }
}
return false;
```